# VLC trancode avi to mp4 (h.264) not playable on iOS

Tags: vlc, libvlc, libvlcsharp, vlckit

I'm using VLC (vlckit) transcode media option but the mp4 is not playable within iOS natively (it does play on all other platforms):

VLC Transcode logs:

```
$":sout=#transcode{venc={module=avcodec{codec=h264_videotoolbox}, vcodec=h264},venc={module=vpx{quality-mode=2},vcodec=VP80},samplerate=44100,soverlay}:file{dst={destination},mux=ts}".
```

When attempting to save the file to the ios photo library:

```
Info (36494) / mediaserverd(CoreMedia): <<<< FigCustomURLHandling >>>> curll_installHandlerOnQueue: 0x10339c380: handler: 0x10dfd6920 priority: 800
Error (35388) / assetsd(PhotoLibraryServices): Video <private> cannot be saved to the photo library: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11829 UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x128e46e70 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12848}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=<private>, NSURL=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}
Info (35388) / assetsd(PhotoLibraryServices): [saveAssetJob:imageSurface:previewImageSurface:completionHandler:] completed job VideoSaveJob assetUUID 36CEDD80-2E1F-4CDB-A05E-5D81B23DE6A3 with generated video destination path <private>
Info (36494) / mediaserverd(MediaToolbox): <<< URLAsset >>> URLAssetFinalize: Called for asset 0x103330580
Info (36494) / mediaserverd(CoreMedia): <<<< FigCustomURLHandling >>>> curll_invalidateOnQueue: 0x10339c360 called
Info (38616) / Kleensight.Mobile.iOS: Error writing to library: Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3302 "Invalid data" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was a problem writing this asset because the data is invalid and cannot be viewed or played., NSUnderlyingError=0x2833a3c90 {Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3302 "Invalid data" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was a problem writing this asset because the data is invalid and cannot be viewed or played., NSUnderlyingError=0x2833dccc0 {Error Domain=com.apple.photos.error Code=13 "Operation failed because video file is invalid and cannot be played." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Operation failed because video file is invalid and cannot be played.}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try with different data, NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid data}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try with different data, NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid data}
```

Any suggestions on how to tweak these VLC transcode parameters so the output mp4 file is playable on iOS? I've read that only certain h.264 profiles work on iOS (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/videotoolbox/vtcompressionsession/compression_properties/profile_and_level_constants)

```
2021-05-18 11:22:51.868 [32755:14865973] [Debug] libvlc:Copyright © 1996-2019 the VideoLAN team
2021-05-18 11:22:51.868 [32755:14865911] [Debug] libvlc:VLC media player - 3.0.9 Vetinari
2021-05-18 11:22:51.868 [32755:14865850] [Debug] libvlc:revision 3.0.8-262-gb7d4bd2972
2021-05-18 11:22:51.868 [32755:14865846] [Debug] libvlc:configured with /Users/Martz/Projects/vlckit/libvlc/vlc/configure  '--prefix=/Users/Martz/Projects/vlckit/libvlc/vlc/install-iPhoneOS/arm64' '--host=aarch64-apple-darwin14' '--with-contrib=/Users/Martz/Projects/vlckit/libvlc/vlc/contrib/iPhone-aarch64-apple-darwin14-aarch64' '--enable-static' '--enable-dvbpsi' '--enable-avcodec' '--disable-macosx' '--disable-macosx-qtkit' '--disable-macosx-avfoundation' '--disable-shared' '--enable-opus' '--disable-faad' '--disable-lua' '--disable-a52' '--enable-fribidi' '--disable-qt' '--disable-skins2' '--disable-vcd' '--disable-vlc' '--disable-vlm' '--disable-nls' '--disable-sse' '--disable-notify' '--enable-live555' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-swscale' '--disable-projectm' '--enable-libass' '--enable-libxml2' '--disable-goom' '--disable-dvdread' '--disable-dvdnav' '--disable-bluray' '--disable-linsys' '--disable-libva' '--disable-gme' '--disable-tremor' '--enable-vorbis' '--disable-fluidsynth' '--disable-jack' '--disable-pulse' '--disable-mtp' '--enable-ogg' '--enable-speex' '--enable-theora' '--enable-flac' '--disable-screen' '--enable-freetype' '--enable-taglib' '--enable-smb2' '--disable-mmx' '--disable-sparkle' '--disable-addonmanagermodules' '--disable-mad' 'host_alias=aarch64-apple-darwin14' 'CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang' 'CFLAGS=-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk -arch arm64 -O3 -g -miphoneos-version-min=8.4 -DNDEBUG' 'LDFLAGS=-arch arm64 -Wl,-ios_version_min,8.4' 'CPPFLAGS=-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk -arch arm64 -O3 -g -miphoneos-version-min=8.4' 'CXX=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++' 'CXXFLAGS=-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk -arch arm64 -O3 -g -miphoneos-version-min=8.4' 'OBJC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang' 'OBJCFLAGS=-O3 -g' 'CCAS=gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH='
2021-05-18 11:22:51.868 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:Creating an input for 'Detailed pipe 1.avi'
Thread started:  #46
2021-05-18 11:22:51.896 [32755:14866023] [Debug] libvlc:using sout chain=`transcode{venc={module=avcodec{codec=h264_videotoolbox}, vcodec=h264,venc=x264{profile = baseline}},vb=500,venc={module=vpx{quality-mode=2},vcodec=VP80},samplerate=44100,soverlay}:file{dst=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2687A4B5-D96C-4CEF-B8DC-B823938C25DC/Documents/Detailed pipe 1_compressed.mp4,mux=ts}'
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #10
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #47
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #11
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #13
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #14
2021-05-18 11:22:52.015 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:stream=`file'[Debug] libvlc:looking for sout access module matching "file": 7 candidates
2021-05-18 11:22:52.015 [32755:14865850] [Debug] libvlc:set config option: sout-standard-dst to /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2687A4B5-D96C-4CEF-B8DC-B823938C25DC/Documents/Detailed pipe 1_compressed.mp4
2021-05-18 11:22:52.015 [32755:14866142] [Debug] libvlc:looking for sout mux module matching "ts": 11 candidates
2021-05-18 11:22:52.016 [32755:14865846] [Debug] libvlc:set config option: sout-standard-mux to ts
2021-05-18 11:22:52.016 [32755:14866015] [Debug] libvlc:shaping=200000 pcr=70000 dts_delay=400000
2021-05-18 11:22:52.016 [32755:14866015] [Debug] libvlc:muxer support adding stream at any time
2021-05-18 11:22:52.016 [32755:14866015] [Debug] libvlc:using sout stream module "stream_out_standard"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.016 [32755:14866015] [Warning] libvlc:option venc is unknown
2021-05-18 11:22:52.016 [32755:14866015] [Debug] libvlc:set config option: sout-transcode-samplerate to 44100
2021-05-18 11:22:52.016 [32755:14866015] [Debug] libvlc:set config option: sout-transcode-soverlay to (null)
2021-05-18 11:22:52.017 [32755:14865973] 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.017 [32755:14865846] [Debug] libvlc:using sout mux module "mux_ts"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.017 [32755:14866141] [Debug] libvlc:file access output opened (/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2687A4B5-D96C-4CEF-B8DC-B823938C25DC/Documents/Detailed pipe 1_compressed.mp4)
2021-05-18 11:22:52.017 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:using sout access module "file"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.017 [32755:14865911] [Debug] libvlc:looking for sout stream module matching "file": 20 candidates
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #48
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #49
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #17
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #18
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #19
2021-05-18 11:22:52.148 [32755:14866023] [Debug] libvlc:muxer prefers to wait for all ES before starting to mux
2021-05-18 11:22:52.148 [32755:14865846] [Debug] libvlc:using default timeshift path
2021-05-18 11:22:52.148 [32755:14865850] [Debug] libvlc:looking for sout stream module matching "transcode": 20 candidates
2021-05-18 11:22:52.148 [32755:14865973] [Debug] libvlc:using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
2021-05-18 11:22:52.148 [32755:14865973] [Debug] libvlc:`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2687A4B5-D96C-4CEF-B8DC-B823938C25DC/Documents/Detailed%20pipe%201.avi' gives access `file' demux `any' path `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2687A4B5-D96C-4CEF-B8DC-B823938C25DC/Documents/Detailed%20pipe%201.avi'
2021-05-18 11:22:52.148 [32755:14866145] [Debug] libvlc:creating demux: access='file' demux='any' location='/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2687A4B5-D96C-4CEF-B8DC-B823938C25DC/Documents/Detailed%20pipe%201.avi' file='/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2687A4B5-D96C-4CEF-B8DC-B823938C25DC/Documents/Detailed pipe 1.avi'
2021-05-18 11:22:52.149 [32755:14866145] [Debug] libvlc:creating access: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2687A4B5-D96C-4CEF-B8DC-B823938C25DC/Documents/Detailed%20pipe%201.avi
2021-05-18 11:22:52.149 [32755:14866144] [Debug] libvlc:looking for access module matching "file": 20 candidates
2021-05-18 11:22:52.149 [32755:14866139] [Debug] libvlc:using `file/ts:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2687A4B5-D96C-4CEF-B8DC-B823938C25DC/Documents/Detailed pipe 1_compressed.mp4'
2021-05-18 11:22:52.149 [32755:14866142] [Warning] libvlc:option venc is unknown
2021-05-18 11:22:52.149 [32755:14865846] [Debug] libvlc:set config option: sout-transcode-vb to 500[Debug] libvlc:pre-buffering done 1024 bytes in 0s - 7042 KiB/s
2021-05-18 11:22:52.149 [32755:14866015] [Debug] libvlc:using sout stream module "stream_out_transcode"[Debug] libvlc:looking for access_demux module matching "file": 4 candidates
2021-05-18 11:22:52.149 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:looking for stream_directory module matching "any": 1 candidates
2021-05-18 11:22:52.149 [32755:14866148] [Debug] libvlc:looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 25 candidates[Debug] libvlc:Using stream method for AStream*
2021-05-18 11:22:52.149 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:using stream_filter module "record"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.150 [32755:14865973] 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.150 [32755:14866143] 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.150 [32755:14866143] [Debug] libvlc:<list 'hdrl'>
2021-05-18 11:22:52.150 [32755:14866144] [Debug] libvlc:looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_read": 25 candidates
2021-05-18 11:22:52.150 [32755:14865850] [Debug] libvlc:no stream_directory modules matched
2021-05-18 11:22:52.150 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:stream=`transcode'
2021-05-18 11:22:52.151 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:<list 'INFO'>
2021-05-18 11:22:52.151 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:</list 'INFO'>0
2021-05-18 11:22:52.151 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:skipping movi chunk
2021-05-18 11:22:52.151 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:looking for demux module matching "avi": 46 candidates
2021-05-18 11:22:52.151 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:</list 'AVI '>0
2021-05-18 11:22:52.152 [32755:14865973] [Debug] libvlc:<list 'AVI '>
2021-05-18 11:22:52.152 [32755:14865973] [Debug] libvlc:no more data at 70813996
2021-05-18 11:22:52.152 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:* LIST-root size:70813996 pos:0
2021-05-18 11:22:52.152 [32755:14865846] 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.152 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:    |   |   + avih size:56 pos:24[Debug] libvlc:    |   |   + LIST-strl size:116 pos:88
2021-05-18 11:22:52.152 [32755:14865846] 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.152 [32755:14866146] [Debug] libvlc:no access_demux modules matched
2021-05-18 11:22:52.152 [32755:14865911] [Debug] libvlc:using access module "filesystem"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.152 [32755:14866141] [Debug] libvlc:no stream_filter modules matched
2021-05-18 11:22:52.153 [32755:14866144] [Debug] libvlc:</list 'strl'>0
2021-05-18 11:22:52.153 [32755:14865850] [Debug] libvlc:</list 'hdrl'>0
2021-05-18 11:22:52.153 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:    |   + LIST-hdrl size:192 pos:12
2021-05-18 11:22:52.153 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:AVIH: 1 stream, flags  HAS_INDEX IS_INTERLEAVED 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.153 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:stream[0] rate:25000000 scale:1000000 samplesize:0
2021-05-18 11:22:52.153 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:stream[0] video(H264) 704x576 24bpp 25.000000fps
2021-05-18 11:22:52.153 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:selecting program id=0
2021-05-18 11:22:52.154 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:selected standard index for stream[0]
2021-05-18 11:22:52.154 [32755:14865973] [Debug] libvlc:    + RIFF-AVI  size:70813988 pos:0
2021-05-18 11:22:52.154 [32755:14865973] [Debug] libvlc:stream[0] length:396 (based on index)
2021-05-18 11:22:52.154 [32755:14865973] [Debug] libvlc:using demux module "avi"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.154 [32755:14866145] [Debug] libvlc:starting pre-buffering
2021-05-18 11:22:52.154 [32755:14866148] [Debug] libvlc:creating demux: access='file' demux='any' location='/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2687A4B5-D96C-4CEF-B8DC-B823938C25DC/Documents/Detailed%20pipe%201.avi' file='/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2687A4B5-D96C-4CEF-B8DC-B823938C25DC/Documents/Detailed pipe 1.avi'
2021-05-18 11:22:52.154 [32755:14865846] [Debug] libvlc:    |   |   |   + strf size:40 pos:164
2021-05-18 11:22:52.155 [32755:14866147] [Debug] libvlc: (path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2687A4B5-D96C-4CEF-B8DC-B823938C25DC/Documents/Detailed pipe 1.avi)
2021-05-18 11:22:52.155 [32755:14865911] [Debug] libvlc:    |   |   + ISFT size:16 pos:224
2021-05-18 11:22:52.155 [32755:14866141] [Debug] libvlc:    |   + JUNK size:1780 pos:248
2021-05-18 11:22:52.155 [32755:14866144] [Debug] libvlc:    |   + LIST-movi size:70603880 pos:2036
2021-05-18 11:22:52.155 [32755:14865850] [Debug] libvlc:    |   + idx1 size:208064 pos:70605924
2021-05-18 11:22:52.155 [32755:14866139] [Debug] libvlc:received first data after 0 ms
2021-05-18 11:22:52.155 [32755:14866146] [Debug] libvlc:    |   + LIST-INFO size:28 pos:212
2021-05-18 11:22:52.155 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:stream[0] created 9910 index entries
2021-05-18 11:22:52.155 [32755:14866142] [Debug] libvlc:using stream_filter module "cache_read"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.155 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:    |   |   |   + strh size:56 pos:100
2021-05-18 11:22:52.156 [32755:14866015] [Debug] libvlc:attachment of directory-extractor failed for file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2687A4B5-D96C-4CEF-B8DC-B823938C25DC/Documents/Detailed%20pipe%201.avi
2021-05-18 11:22:52.156 [32755:14866143] [Debug] libvlc:<list 'strl'>
2021-05-18 11:22:52.156 [32755:14866023] [Debug] libvlc:looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 25 candidates
Thread started:  #20
2021-05-18 11:22:52.181 [32755:14865850] [Debug] libvlc:switching to async mode
2021-05-18 11:22:52.181 [32755:14866147] [Debug] libvlc:looking for meta reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
2021-05-18 11:22:52.181 [32755:14866144] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 0%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.181 [32755:14866146] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 5%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.181 [32755:14866146] [Debug] libvlc:found NAL_PPS (pps_id=0 sps_id=0)
2021-05-18 11:22:52.181 [32755:14866146] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 22%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.181 [32755:14866146] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 25%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.181 [32755:14866145] [Debug] libvlc:looking for packetizer module matching "any": 25 candidates
2021-05-18 11:22:52.182 [32755:14866145] [Debug] libvlc:set config option: sout-transcode-module to avcodec{codec=h264_videotoolbox}
2021-05-18 11:22:52.182 [32755:14866145] [Debug] libvlc:set config option: sout-transcode-vcodec to h264
2021-05-18 11:22:52.182 [32755:14866146] [Debug] libvlc:trying configuration venc={module=avcodec{codec=h264_videotoolbox}, vcodec=h264,venc=x264{profile = baseline}}
2021-05-18 11:22:52.182 [32755:14865850] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 12%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.182 [32755:14866141] [Debug] libvlc:`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2687A4B5-D96C-4CEF-B8DC-B823938C25DC/Documents/Detailed%20pipe%201.avi' successfully opened[Debug] libvlc:Buffering 32%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.182 [32755:14866141] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 35%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.182 [32755:14866142] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 10%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.182 [32755:14866142] [Debug] libvlc:Checking video codec mapping for h264 got h264 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.183 [32755:14866023] [Debug] libvlc:adding a new sout input for `h264` (sout_input: 0x282afb380)
2021-05-18 11:22:52.183 [32755:14866023] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 42%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.183 [32755:14866148] [Debug] libvlc:using packetizer module "h264"[Debug] libvlc:creating video transcoding from fcc=`h264' to fcc=`h264'[Debug] libvlc:Buffering 2%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.183 [32755:14866148] [Debug] libvlc:looking for video decoder module matching "any": 12 candidates
2021-05-18 11:22:52.183 [32755:14866148] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 45%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.183 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 17%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.183 [32755:14866015] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 20%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.183 [32755:14866142] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 40%[Debug] libvlc:Buffering 52%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.183 [32755:14866023] 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.183 [32755:14866139] 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.183 [32755:14866146] [Warning] libvlc:option venc is unknown
2021-05-18 11:22:52.184 [32755:14865850] 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.184 [32755:14865850] [Debug] libvlc:new PPS parsed: 0
2021-05-18 11:22:52.184 [32755:14866144] [Debug] libvlc:found NAL_SPS (sps_id=0)
2021-05-18 11:22:52.184 [32755:14866148] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 47%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.184 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 50%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.184 [32755:14866015] 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.184 [32755:14866015] [Warning] libvlc:forcing CVPX format: 420v
2021-05-18 11:22:52.184 [32755:14866142] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 55%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.184 [32755:14866142] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 75%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.185 [32755:14865911] [Debug] libvlc:no meta reader modules matched
2021-05-18 11:22:52.185 [32755:14865911] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 80%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.185 [32755:14865911] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 82%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.185 [32755:14865911] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 85%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.185 [32755:14865911] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 87%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.185 [32755:14865911] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 90%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.185 [32755:14866015] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 72%[Debug] libvlc:Buffering 92%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.186 [32755:14866142] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 77%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.186 [32755:14866147] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 15%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.186 [32755:14865850] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 62%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.186 [32755:14866144] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 65%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.186 [32755:14866143] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 27%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.186 [32755:14866148] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 67%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.186 [32755:14865973] [Debug] libvlc:looking for a subtitle file in /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2687A4B5-D96C-4CEF-B8DC-B823938C25DC/Documents/
2021-05-18 11:22:52.186 [32755:14866023] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 57%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.186 [32755:14866015] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 95%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.186 [32755:14865846] [Debug] libvlc:starting in sync mode
2021-05-18 11:22:52.186 [32755:14866147] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 100%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.187 [32755:14865850] [Debug] libvlc:Stream buffering done (1025 ms in 28 ms)
2021-05-18 11:22:52.187 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 70%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.187 [32755:14865911] 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.187 [32755:14866139] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 60%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.187 [32755:14866142] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 97%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.187 [32755:14866141] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 37%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.187 [32755:14866146] [Debug] libvlc:new SPS parsed: 0
2021-05-18 11:22:52.187 [32755:14866145] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 30%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.188 [32755:14865912] [Debug] libvlc:Buffering 7%
2021-05-18 11:22:52.220 [32755:14866143] [Debug] libvlc:using ffmpeg Lavc58.6.103
2021-05-18 11:22:52.220 [32755:14865846] [Warning] libvlc:vt session error: 'kVTVideoDecoderMalfunctionErr'
2021-05-18 11:22:52.221 [32755:14866147] [Error] libvlc:option quiet does not exist
2021-05-18 11:22:52.221 [32755:14865850] [Debug] libvlc:CPU flags: 0x00000068
2021-05-18 11:22:52.221 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:allowing 6 thread(s) for decoding
2021-05-18 11:22:52.221 [32755:14866146] [Debug] libvlc:using frame thread mode with 6 threads
2021-05-18 11:22:52.221 [32755:14866144] [Debug] libvlc:looking for encoder module matching "avcodec": 15 candidates
2021-05-18 11:22:52.221 [32755:14866144] [Debug] libvlc:CPU flags: 0x00000068
2021-05-18 11:22:52.222 [32755:14866144] [Debug] libvlc:set config option: sout-avcodec-codec to h264_videotoolbox
2021-05-18 11:22:52.222 [32755:14866146] [Debug] libvlc:using ffmpeg Lavc58.6.103
2021-05-18 11:22:52.222 [32755:14865973] [Debug] libvlc:codec (h264) started
2021-05-18 11:22:52.222 [32755:14866145] [Debug] libvlc:using video decoder module "avcodec"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.222 [32755:14866023] [Error] libvlc:option quiet does not exist
2021-05-18 11:22:52.223 [32755:14866141] [Debug] libvlc:Time base for probing set to 1000/25000
2021-05-18 11:22:52.223 [32755:14865846] [Debug] libvlc:Time base set to 1000/25000
2021-05-18 11:22:52.223 [32755:14865846] [Debug] libvlc:rc buffer size 2000000 bits
Thread started:  #21
2021-05-18 11:22:52.319 [32755:14865911] [Error] libvlc:Unknown option "border_mask"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.319 [32755:14866146] [Error] libvlc:Unknown option "qsquish"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.319 [32755:14866142] [Debug] libvlc:found encoder H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)
2021-05-18 11:22:52.319 [32755:14866148] [Error] libvlc:Unknown option "lmin"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.319 [32755:14866139] [Error] libvlc:Unknown option "lmax"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.319 [32755:14866144] [Error] libvlc:Unknown option "noise_reduction"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.319 [32755:14865973] [Error] libvlc:Unknown option "rc_buffer_aggressivity"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.319 [32755:14866143] [Debug] libvlc:using encoder module "avcodec"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.319 [32755:14866145] [Debug] libvlc:removing module "avcodec"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.325 [32755:14865846] [Notice] libvlc:using venc={module=avcodec{codec=h264_videotoolbox}, vcodec=h264,venc=x264{profile = baseline}} configuration for transcoding
2021-05-18 11:22:52.325 [32755:14866015] [Debug] libvlc:Decoder wait done in 142 ms
Thread started:  #22
2021-05-18 11:22:52.350 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:available hardware decoder output format 160 (videotoolbox_vld)
2021-05-18 11:22:52.350 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:available software decoder output format 0 (yuv420p)
2021-05-18 11:22:52.350 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:Checking if filter chain I420 -> NV12 is possible
2021-05-18 11:22:52.350 [32755:14866147] [Debug] libvlc:looking for video converter module matching "any": 15 candidates
2021-05-18 11:22:52.350 [32755:14866144] [Debug] libvlc:using video converter module "i420_nv12"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.350 [32755:14866144] [Debug] libvlc:Filter 'i420_nv12' (0x109eb9110) appended to chain
2021-05-18 11:22:52.350 [32755:14866144] [Debug] libvlc:removing module "i420_nv12"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.350 [32755:14866144] [Debug] libvlc:Filter 0x109eb9110 removed from chain
2021-05-18 11:22:52.350 [32755:14866144] [Debug] libvlc:Filter chain testing done, input chroma I420 seems to be possible for transcode
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866015] [Debug] libvlc:source fps 25/1, destination 25/1
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866015] [Debug] libvlc:source pixel aspect is 0.996540:1
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866141] [Debug] libvlc:encoder aspect is 704:578
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866141] [Debug] libvlc:looking for video converter module matching "any": 15 candidates
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866141] [Debug] libvlc:Filter 'i420_nv12' (0x11f937690) appended to chain
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866148] [Debug] libvlc:destination (after video filters) 704x578
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:CPU flags: 0x00000068[Debug] libvlc:scaled pixel aspect is 0.996540:1[Debug] libvlc:set config option: sout-avcodec-codec to h264_videotoolbox
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:rc buffer size 2000000 bits
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866146] [Debug] libvlc:using video converter module "i420_nv12"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14865911] [Error] libvlc:option quiet does not exist[Debug] libvlc:decoder aspect is 1.217993:1
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866145] 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866023] [Debug] libvlc:source 704x576, destination 704x576
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866139] 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866147] 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14865846] [Debug] libvlc:Time base set to 1/25
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866015] [Debug] libvlc:source chroma: I420, destination NV12
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866148] [Debug] libvlc:Time base for probing set to 1/25
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866141] [Debug] libvlc:using ffmpeg Lavc58.6.103
2021-05-18 11:22:52.355 [32755:14866142] [Debug] libvlc:looking for encoder module matching "avcodec": 15 candidates
2021-05-18 11:22:52.418 [32755:14866143] [Error] libvlc:Unknown option "border_mask"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.418 [32755:14866143] [Debug] libvlc:adding a new input
2021-05-18 11:22:52.418 [32755:14866139] [Debug] libvlc:adding input codec=h264 pid=100
2021-05-18 11:22:52.418 [32755:14866023] [Debug] libvlc:using encoder module "avcodec"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.418 [32755:14865850] [Error] libvlc:Unknown option "lmin"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.418 [32755:14866146] [Error] libvlc:Unknown option "qsquish"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.418 [32755:14866145] [Error] libvlc:Unknown option "rc_buffer_aggressivity"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.418 [32755:14865911] [Debug] libvlc:found encoder H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)
2021-05-18 11:22:52.418 [32755:14865912] [Error] libvlc:Unknown option "lmax"
2021-05-18 11:22:52.418 [32755:14866147] [Error] libvlc:Unknown option "noise_reduction"[Debug] libvlc:new PCR PID is 100
2021-05-18 11:22:52.418 [32755:14866140] 
2021-05-18 11:22:52.492 [32755:14866142] [Warning] libvlc:almost fed libavcodec with two frames with the same PTS (36713941)
[Removed many lines like the line above to save space in this post]
2021-05-18 11:23:24.157 [32755:14866143] [Warning] libvlc:cannot get packet header, track disabled
2021-05-18 11:23:24.157 [32755:14866142] [Debug] libvlc:EOF reached
2021-05-18 11:23:24.157 [32755:14865850] [Debug] libvlc:waiting decoder fifos to empty
2021-05-18 11:23:24.173 [32755:14866144] [Warning] libvlc:almost fed libavcodec with two frames with the same PTS (36723816)
2021-05-18 11:23:24.263 [32755:14866015] [Debug] libvlc:removing module "h264"[Debug] libvlc:removing a sout input (sout_input: 0x282afb380)
2021-05-18 11:23:24.263 [32755:14865912] 
2021-05-18 11:23:24.263 [32755:14866145] [Debug] libvlc:killing decoder fourcc `h264'
2021-05-18 11:23:24.275 [32755:14866023] [Warning] libvlc:cannot encode one frame
2021-05-18 11:23:24.276 [32755:14866139] [Debug] libvlc:removing module "avcodec"
2021-05-18 11:23:24.277 [32755:14866147] [Debug] libvlc:removing module "avcodec"
2021-05-18 11:23:24.288 [32755:14866142] [Debug] libvlc:Filter 0x11f937690 removed from chain
2021-05-18 11:23:24.289 [32755:14866143] [Debug] libvlc:removing module "i420_nv12"
2021-05-18 11:23:24.289 [32755:14866141] [Debug] libvlc:freeing video PID 100
2021-05-18 11:23:24.289 [32755:14866144] [Warning] libvlc:no more input streams for this mux
2021-05-18 11:23:24.289 [32755:14866148] [Debug] libvlc:removing module "record"
2021-05-18 11:23:24.289 [32755:14866140] [Debug] libvlc:removing module "avi"
2021-05-18 11:23:24.289 [32755:14865850] [Debug] libvlc:removing input pid=100
2021-05-18 11:23:24.289 [32755:14865850] [Debug] libvlc:removing module "filesystem"
2021-05-18 11:23:24.289 [32755:14865846] [Debug] libvlc:removing module "cache_read"
2021-05-18 11:23:24.289 [32755:14865846] [Debug] libvlc:Program doesn't contain anymore ES
```

Comment: share logs please

Comment: I've added the logs above.

Comment: share the player logs please

Comment: Added the log when attempting to save to the library - error indicates the video could not be played.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to transcode audio to "mp4a". Also change mux to "mp4". This should works. "vb" and "ab" set as you need.

```
:sout=#transcode{venc=avcodec, vcodec=h264, vb=2048, acodec=m4a, ab=128, samplerate=44100}:std{access=file, mux=mp4, dst=PATH}
```

Comment: One more thing. You need to explicit call player.stop() after player state change to "stopped". Without that file will be corrupted